# Cronjob stuck in a reboot loop

Tags: linux, reboot, cron

I have added a rather simple cronjob to my machine to perform a daily reboot at a given time (in this example 06:30)

```
30 6 * * * reboot
```

I may be misunderstanding something completely here, but the problem that I have is that this results in my machine continuously rebooting until the next full hour (in this case for 30 minutes, so at 7 it stops).

To give a second example: If I add the following cronjob, the reboot loop goes on for one hour (from 6 till 7).

```
0 6 * * * reboot
```

Am I missing something here? What might be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer to my problem. The device I am running my cronjobs on does not have a real-time clock. This leads to that loop of reboots.

One solution is to use a delay and touch a file in /etc before reboot.
A working example on systems without a real-time clock may look like this:
`00 6 * * * sleep 70 && touch /etc/banner && reboot`

For more information regarding this you may look at: https://oldwiki.archive.openwrt.org/doc/howto/cron#periodic_reboot_of_a_router

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an issue with your crown entry per-se - Its more likely your system is suffering from clock drift and this is causing a weird anomilous effect.

Either that or you are using a very nonstandard version of cron or this is caused by a different job...

Comment: I am quite certain that clock drift is not the cause of this. I have been checking the clock regularly and noticed nothing suspicious or wrong.

This is the only cronjob that I have defined. How would I know what version of cron I am using? 

What I did now to mitigate the problem is that I simply set the time of reboot to minute 59 eg: `59 6 * * * reboot`

For now it works like this, but I'd love to understand whats happening here